# How to use a video as an avcapture input

Tags: macos, video-capture, avcapture

Trying to test a variety of camera inputs against an application, but since it would be prohibitive to get the webcam to do the exact same thing every time, and to change lenses, would like to just shoot videos and use it as an input.

I can see how to query OSX for AVCapture devices, but is it possible create one and register it with the system, while feeding it frames from a saved video file?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm encountering the exact same problem.